# what is behavior when char is compared with unsigned short in c language?

Tags: c, char, compare, unsigned

When I run the following program:

```
void func(unsigned short maxNum, unsigned short di)
{
    if (di == 0) {
        return;
    }

    char i;

    for (i = di; i <= maxNum; i += di) {
        printf("%u ", i);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    func(256, 100);
    return 0;
}
```

It is endless loop, but i wonder when char is compared with unsigned short, is char translated to unsigned short? In this situation, char is overflow and larger than maxNum. I really do not know how to explain the results of this program.

Comment: I guess `char` isn't translated to `unsigned short`.

Comment: @Lucas yes, both char and unsigned short are translated to signed int....amazing

Answer (score 2):

**Implementation defined behavior**, **Undefined behavior** and **`CHAR_MAX < 256`**

---

Let us sort out:

```
... unsigned short maxNum
... unsigned short di
char i;
for (i = di; i <= maxNum; i += di) {
    printf("%u ", i);
}
```

`char` may be a *signed* `char` or an *unsigned* `char`.  Let us assume it is *signed*.

`unsigned short` may have the same range as `unsigned` when both are 16-bit.  Yet it is more common to find `unsigned short` as 16-bit and `int, unsigned` as 32-bit.

Other possibles exist, yet let us go forward with the above two assumptions.

`i = di` could be interesting if the value assigned was outside the range of a `char`, but 100 is always within `char` range, so `i` is 100.

Each argument in `i <= maxNum` goes through *usual integer promotions* so the *signed* `char i` first becomes an `int 100` and the 16-bit `maxNum` becomes an `int 256`.  As `100 < 256` is true, the loop body is entered.  Notice `i` would never expect to have a value as large as 256 since `CHAR_MAX` is less than 256 - even on following loops - This explains the seen forever loop.  [But wait there's more](https://media1.tenor.com/images/6cf2da8392e657c2e0997b0eadb60667/tenor.gif)

With `printf("%u ", i);`, `printf()` expects a matching `unsigned` argument.  But `i` as a type with less range then `int` gets promoted to a `int` with the same value as part of a ... argument.  Usually printing mis-matched specifiers and type is **undefined behavior** with an exception: when the value is representable as both a signed and unsigned type.  As 100 is the first time, all is OK.

At the loop end, `i += di` is like `i = i + di;`.  The addition arguments go through  *usual integer promotions* and become `int 100` added to `int 100`.  That sum is 200.  So far nothing strange.  Yet assigning a 200 to a *signed* `char` coverts the 200 as it is out of range.  This is **implementation defined behavior**.  The assigned value could have been 0 or 1 or 2....  Typically, the value is wrapped around ("modded") by adding/subtracting 256 until in range.  100 + 100 -256 --> -56.

But the 2nd `printf("%u ", i);` attempts printing -56 and *that* is **undefined behavior**.

---

Tip: enable all warnings,  Good compilers will point out many of these problems and save you time.

Comment: I was just wondering, if there's any good reason for wrapping the value until in range?

Comment: @Lucas With 2's complement signed types, wrapping is the same as ignoring the upper bits. So with 32-bit to 8-bit,  0x12345678 becomes 0x78.  Quite simply to employ.

Comment: I'm just little bit confused. You are saying _"With 2's complement signed types, wrapping is the same as ignoring the upper bits"_. Okay, I agree with the example 0x12345678 becomes 0x78. But It's still obscure. If `char a = 127` and then `a++` yields the value `-128`. i.e. in signed-magnitude presentation `127 = 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1` and increasing it with 1 `= 127 + 1 = 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 = -128`. Here we aren't 2's complementing the 127 or wrapping the value (although we can assume), we are just adding 1 to the value 127 which yields the value -128 for signed types.

Comment: One more thing in `signed-magnitude representation`, `1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`(8 bits only) should be equal to `-0` then why it is being equal to `-128`? If we increase the number of **ignored bits(in 16 bits)**, i.e. `1111 1111 1000 0000`, it makes sense that `1000 0000 = 128` and the rest `1111 1111` are representing `-`. But it doesn't makes sense in 8-bits which is `1000 0000 = -128`. How?

Comment: Please help me, my head's gonna explode!

Comment: @Lucas " in signed-magnitude presentation 127 = 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 and increasing it with 1 = 127 + 1 = 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 = -128" is false.  1) that is what happens with 2's complement. 2) Why are you considering _signed-magnitude_?

Comment: 1) How? 2) Because we are discussing about signed types.

Comment: 2's complement of `127` is `-127`. Isn't it?

Comment: @Lucas _2's complement_ can refer to an [operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) or an [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two's_complement).  Perhaps after you have reviewed your notes, post an new question if needed.

Comment: I have been referring  to the encoding.  You have been referring to the operation, which is not so important to this code. "2's complement of 127 is -127." is true, but not an issue here.  The 200 does not convert to -56 by taking the 2's complement  of 200, but by adding/subtracting 256 until in range.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/11/21/integer-promotion/  , both char and unsigned short are translated to int which can explain the process and result of this programs.