# Why data overflow in a `char` data type causes wrappping the value within its range?

Tags: c, char

I recently came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62844665/what-is-behavior-when-char-is-compared-with-unsigned-short-in-c-language) question and the answer given by [@chux - Reinstate Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica).

Quoting lines from their answer, *"This is implementation-defined behavior. The assigned value could have been 0 or 1 or 2... Typically, the value is wrapped around ("modded") by adding/subtracting 256 until in range. `100 + 100 -256 --> -56`."*

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
 char a = 127;
 a++;
 printf("%d", a);
 return 0;
}
```

**Output:** `-128`

---

In most of the C compilers, `char` type takes `1 Byte` size and strictly speaking, I'm assuming its 16-bit system and `char` takes `1 Byte`.

When `a = 127`, its binary representation inside the computer is `0111 1111`, increasing it with 1 should yield the value

> `0111 1111 + 0000 0001 = 1000 0000`

which is equal to `-0`(considering, signed-number representation, where left-most bit represents `0 = + and 1 = -`) then why the output is equal to `-128`?

Is it because of the *"INTEGER PROMOTION RULE"*? I mean, for this expression `a + 1`, `a` gets converted to `int (2 Bytes)` before the `+` operation and then its binary representation in the memory becomes `1111 1111 1000 0000` which is equal to `-128` and makes sense to the output `-128`. But then this assumption of mine conflicts with the quoted lines of *Chux-Reinstate-Monica* about wrapping the values.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217680/discussion-on-question-by-lucas-why-data-overflow-in-a-char-data-type-causes-w).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is behavior when char is compared with unsigned short in c language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62844665/what-is-behavior-when-char-is-compared-with-unsigned-short-in-c-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1000 0000 which is equal to -0...

[Ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) has a -0, but most computers use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) which does not.

In [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) notation the left-most bit represents `-(coefficient_bit * 2^N-1)` i.e. in your case, `1000 0000` the left-most bit represents `-(1 * 2^8-1)` which is equal to `-128` and that's why the output is the same.

Your `char` is an 8 bit signed integer in which case 1000 0000 is -128. We can test what 1000 0000 is conveniently using the [GNU extension which allows binary constants](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html).

```
char a = 0b10000000;
printf("%d\n", a);    // -128
```

`char`, in this implementation, is a signed 8-bit integer. Adding 1 to 127 causes integer overflow to -128.

What about integer promotion? Integer promotion happens *during* the calculation, but the result is still a `char`. 128 can't fit in our signed 8-bit char, so it overflows to -128.

Integer promotion is demonstrated by [this example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/integer-promotions-in-c/).

```
char a = 30, b = 40;
char c = (a * b);
printf("%d\n", c);      // -80

char d = (a * b) / 10;
printf("%d\n", d);      // 120
```

`char c = (a * b);` is -80, but `char d = (a * b) / 10;` is 120. Why? Shouldn't it be -8? The answer here *is* integer promotion. The math is done as native integers, but the result must still be stuffed into an 8-bit char. `(30 * 40)` is 1200 which is 0100 1011 0000. Then it must be stuffed back into an 8 bit signed integer; that's 1011 0000 or -80.

For the other calculation, `(30 * 40) / 10` == `1200 / 10` == 120 which fits just fine.

Comment: This answer doesn't explains my question. But thanks btw. Most of its part I read already. Would you mind reading **@rici** comment?

Comment: @Lucas I've read the comment thread, and rici said the same thing: you get -128 because computers use 2's compliment, not 1's. Sorry, what is left unexplained?

Comment: @Lucas I see, you needed 2's complement explained. Thanks for the edit.